# How to check if a table is visible or not with javascript?

Tags: javascript, visibility

first of all i'll explain the situation:

1. I can **ONLY** write in the body of an html, this is because of some limitations.
2. I need to replace the website (a profile) for a new one.
3. The issue is: the menu should show or hide sections on click... and isn't.
4. I don't really know much of javascript, just a bit of python and because of that i'm getting some issues with the code, but i won't learn javascript much either since this will probably be just a once in a lifetime for me.
5. I don't want to add jQuery code.

So... i tried this code in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_background, (copy and pasty so you can also check) but it doesnt works as expected, the function for the menu isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script>
function comandos() 
{
var visibilidaddecomandos = document.getElementById("comandos").style.display;
  if (visibilidaddecomandos == "hidden")
  {
    document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else if (visibilidaddecomandos == "visible")
  {
    document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
return false;
}

document.write('<style> #navcontainer { margin: 10px 0 0 30px; padding: 0; height: 20px; } #navcontainer ul { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; text-align: center; } #navcontainer ul li { display: block; float: left; text-align: center; padding: 0; margin: 0; } #navcontainer ul li a { background: #fff; width: 78px; height: 18px; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; border-right: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0; color: #666; text-decoration: none; display: block; text-align: center; font: normal 10px/18px verdana; } #navcontainer ul li a:hover { color: #6659A7; background: #eeeeee; } #navcontainer a:active { background: #c60; color: #fff; } #navcontainer li#active a { background: #c60; border: 1px solid #c60; color: #fff; } </style> <div id="navcontainer"> <ul> <li><a href="#" OnClick="comandos()"><span>Comandos</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Estadisticas</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Juegos</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Sobre mi</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Saelyth</span></a></li></ul> </div>');

document.write('<br><table id="global" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:460px; height:600px"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><table id="comandos" border="2" style="background-color:#000000; float:center"><tr><td><p style="color:red">Testing the ID table "comandos"</p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>');


document.body.style.background="#66ffff url('http://images.wikia.com/xenosaga/images/8/86/KOSMOSWikiBG.jpg') no-repeat left top"
document.title = "¡My not working menu!";
window.stop();
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Why in the world are you uisng document.write to write out the html for the page? Yikes.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to make it easier for everyone to see what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/q8j4r/

Comment: Thanks Broxzier, and epascarello: because i need to replace the basic profile in a website and put a custom created one by me, just a random experiment and this code works fine to replace the entire html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although tables are not best practice..for multiple reasons.. one being that the entire table has to load before your data is shown.

Divs are your best friend.

Anyways, here is the fix I believe you are looking for.

```
 function comandos() 
{
var visibilidaddecomandos = document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility;
  if (visibilidaddecomandos == "hidden")
  {
    document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else if (visibilidaddecomandos == "visible")
  {
    document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
return false;
}
```

Also you have to add a default visibility to your table in order for it to work.

```
<table id="comandos" border="2" style="visibility:visible;background-color:#000000; float:center">
```

Comment: That was all the time! i had to add a default visibility on the table code :D Thanks for the right answer. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var visibilidaddecomandos = document.getElementById("comandos");
  if (visibilidaddecomandos.style.visibility == 'hidden')
  {
    visibilidaddecomandos.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else if (visibilidaddecomandos.style.visibility == "visible")
  {
    visibilidaddecomandos.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

This will work....

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

if (document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility == "hidden"){document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility == "visible";}else if (document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility == "visible")
{document.getElementById("comandos").style.visibility == "hidden";}

Hope this will help.

Comment: tried in the tryit editor... and not working or i'm too noob to make it works.